# Special character issue with recordsets read from MySQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql, xml, vb.net

I have recordsets in my MySQL database like this (in german):

> Karrieren im Portrait: Interview mit Thorsten Franck – „Ich liebe Produkte“

Now when I get the data with the MySQL connector reader and write it into an xml file I get just this:

> Karrieren im Portrait: Interview mit Thorsten Franck  Ich liebe Produkte

As you (hopefully) can see, the minus (it's one of those long ones) and the upper and lower quote signs are not shown.

The table is defined as UTF-8, the output of the xml file also.

Any idea how I could solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql `show variables like '%char%'`, is it all utf-8?

> in php connection to mysql, use `mysql_set_charset` to utf-8

http://forums.asp.net/t/1619144.aspx?collation+and+charset+Problem+In+MySql

Comment: 'character_set_database' is currently set to 'latin1' and
'character_set_filesystem' is 'binary'. Everything else is set to utf-8. Anyway I'm using ASP.net not PHP.

Comment: great, similar question except ASP vs PHP -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143853/utf-8-problem-when-saving-to-mysql/ can try character_set_client set to utf8 as well?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The datase column was still defined as latin1. Now it works just fine.