# Problems with certain characters in jQuery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, encoding, utf-8

I am having problems with some characters after I added some jQuery to my code.

http://www.blueskycouncil.com/login-form.php (login: stack/this)

It worked fine when I was just doing it all in php but now it converts some of the characters weirdly.

This is the jQuery code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check to see if document is ready

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Set sort mode to Best        

    $.post("_db_index.php", 
        {sort_id: "best"},

            // Take data from _db_index.php and put it into the HTML
            function(output){
                $('#left').html(output).show();
        });

    });
        // Check to see whether user have voted on item before 
        function updateKarma(element, id, sortId){
          $.post("idea_karma.php", 
              {pagetype: "index", karmatype: "ideaspace", id: id, sort_id: sortId}, 

        function(output){
                element.parentNode.className="karma-btn_voted";
              element.parentNode.innerHTML="<span class=\"voted\">"+output+"</span>";
          });

              return false;
        }

        function viewMode(sortId){
            $.post("_db_index.php", 

                {sort_id: sortId},
                    function(output){
                    $('#left').html(output).show();

                    $.post("subnavigation.php", 
                        {sort_id: sortId},

                            function(output){
                            $('#base').html(output).show();
                        });


                    });




            };

                $(function(){  
                 $(".base a").hover(function(){  
                  $(this).children("span").fadeOut();  
                 }, function(){  
                  $(this).children("span").fadeIn();  
                 })    
                });
```

and in the _db_index.php file it fetch it like this

```
<?php

// Start session

require_once('auth.php');
require_once('config.php');
require_once('db_open_select.php');

// Functions

include('trunctate_text.php');

$sort_id = $_POST['sort_id'];
$member_id = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

// Check for PHP Insert Hack
if(array_key_exists("sort_id",$_POST)){
    $sort_allowed = array("best","new","comments");
        if(in_array($_POST["sort_id"],$sort_allowed)){
            $sort_id = $_POST["sort_id"];
        }
}

echo "<div id=\"gradient\">";

        //If User selected Best Rated or if url is empty:
        if (empty($_POST) OR $sort_id == "best") {

            //Perform database query
             $result = mysql_query("SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM comments C WHERE C.idea_id = I.id) AS COMMENTS, ( SELECT login FROM members M WHERE I.member_id = M.member_id ) as login FROM ideaspace I ORDER BY KARMA DESC", $connection); 
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT idea_id FROM vote_idea WHERE member_id = $member_id", $connection);


            //Create array with which ideas the current user has voted on already
                $user_voted_on_this = array();

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                        {
                         $user_voted_on_this[] = $row["idea_id"];
                        }

                //If User selected newest:
                } elseif ($sort_id == "new") {

                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM comments C WHERE C.idea_id = I.id) AS COMMENTS, ( SELECT login FROM members M WHERE I.member_id = M.member_id ) as login FROM ideaspace I ORDER BY DATE DESC", $connection); 
                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT idea_id FROM vote_idea WHERE member_id = $member_id", $connection);

                            //Create array with which ideas the current user has voted on already
                                $user_voted_on_this = array();

                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                                        {
                                         $user_voted_on_this[] = $row["idea_id"];
                                        } 

                        //If User selected most commented:                
                            } else {

                                if ($sort_id == "comments")

                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT( 1 ) FROM comments C WHERE C.idea_id = I.id) AS COMMENTS, ( SELECT login FROM members M WHERE I.member_id = M.member_id ) as login FROM ideaspace I ORDER BY COMMENTS DESC", $connection); 
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT idea_id FROM vote_idea WHERE member_id = $member_id", $connection);



                                    $user_voted_on_this = array();

                                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                                            {
                                             $user_voted_on_this[] = $row["idea_id"];
                                            }  

                }

                if (!$result && !$query) {    
                    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
                }



        // 4. Use data from database
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo 
                "<dt id=\"idea\">";

                        if (in_array($row['id'],$user_voted_on_this)) {

                                        echo 
                                            "<div class=\"karma-btn_voted\">
                                                <span class=\"voted\">{$row['karma']}</span>
                                                    </div>";

                                                    } else { 

                                        echo 
                                            "<div class=\"karma-btn\">

                        <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"return updateKarma(this,'{$row['id']}', '$sort_id')\"><img src=\"images/btn_lrg_karma.png\" alt=\"Alternative text\"><span class=\"voted\"><div class=\"newkarma\">{$row['karma']}</div></span></a>
                                            </div>";    

                            }

                                        echo    
                                            "<div class=\"textbox\">
                                                <P class=\"category\">" . $row['category'] . "</p>
                                                    <P class=\"headline\"> <a href=\"details_idea.php?itemid={$row['id']}\">" . $row['d_header']."</a></P>
                                                        <P>" . $shortdesc = myTruncate($row['d_description'], 220, " ") . "</p>" .
                                                            "<P class=\"name\">Submitted by " . $row['login'] . " " . date('D d Y', strtotime($row['date'])) . "<img src=\"images/comments.png\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"#\">". $row['COMMENTS'] ."</a></p>" .

                                                                    "</div>
                                                                        </dt></div>";


        }



?>


    <?Php
    require_once('db_close.php');
    ?>
```

As I said it worked fine when it was PHP but now that i fetch the data it replaces some characters with diamond ? character icon.

Comment: You have quite a few validation errors; you might want to take care of those. Also your first code sample is incomplete, and so is your question.

Comment: sorry fixed the question and added the entire code snippet

Comment: You page looks pretty messed up in my browser. What's that &lt;dt&gt; tag for?  Think you should change that Php to php, not sure if that's a typo or not.

Comment: <div class=\"newkarma\">{$row['karma']}</div>

Comment: should that be: <div class=\"newkarma\">". $row['karma'] ."</div>  It's been a while since I played with PHP.

Comment: you can do {$row['karma']} that all works fine. I had no problem with the php before I started to add jQuery.

Comment: Sephrial I am curious what kind of browser are you using? I have checked this in firefox, chrome, safari, IE8 without any major problems.

Comment: Probably fixing this will not solve your problem bu, you declare your encoding outside `<head>`: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />  <head>`

Answer (score 2):

is an encoding issue, lots of things to check - [UTF-8 problem when saving to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143853/utf-8-problem-when-saving-to-mysql/4143922#4143922)

Comment: thnx, but I didn't have the problem before I used jQuery. It's only when I read data and apparently only ' as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ThomPete - previously u probably did not run into same set of the data like the one u having now

Comment: I believe ajreal is right - this probably doesn't have anything to do with jQuery, your browser might've interpreted it correctly when it was directly on page, however now that you're getting those data via AJAX, it would probably work differently and serve what you output (which is an incorrectly encoded output)

Answer (score 1):

The  response is encoded in cp1252, but your page in UTF8

The char that disappears has decimal-code  146

```
’
```

You should  change the encoding before you send the response(or better before you insert the data to the db).

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "CP1252");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone I fixed it

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); in the db_connection file.